# Header on resizing not 100% anymore

Tags: css, header, resize, scroll

What I got is this code of CSS:

```
#menu_top{
margin: 0;
position:fixed;
background: #4d4d4d;
width: 100%;
height: 90px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

and this for javascript:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $('#menu_top').css('left',-$(window).scrollLeft());
});
```

But when I resize my window, to a very small Dimension the header isn't 100% of width anymore. It is not completely filling everything when scrolling to right.

So how can I do a complete window filling 100% even on resizing?

Answer (score 1):

You must give `#menu_top` the `min-width` of the element wich is the widest.

http://jsfiddle.net/XhRaB/